# How can I unlock DLC-specific magicks in Adventure?

Tags: magicka

The spells introduced by The Stars are Left are pretty neat, can I enable them in the original campaign? I'm fine with a lil bit of modding and save editing, as long as it does not break online play.

I'm running the latest version (1.4.6.5) for the PC.

Answer (score 1):

Any modding will break online play for you, as you will no longer be running the same version as everyone else.  The Magicka data is stored in .sav files, which cannot be opened with most editors.  It looks like you're out of luck.